# Mockito NullPointerException - Not recognizing repository

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, mockito

I'm having trouble figuring out why Mockito is throwing a NullPointerException when I'm telling the mock to return `true`.

Here is my JUnit Test:

```
public class PizzaValidatorTest {

  private Pizza meatPizza;

  private PizzaValidator validator = new PizzaValidator();

  @MockBean
  private IngredientRepository ingredientRepository;

  @MockBean
  private PizzaSizeRepository pizzaSizeRepository;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {

    meatPizza = new Pizza();

    validator = new PizzaValidator();
  }

  @Test
  public void validateValid() {
    when(ingredientRepository.existsById(any())).thenReturn(true);
    when(pizzaSizeRepository.existsById(any())).thenReturn(true);
    assertTrue(validator.validate(meatPizza));
  }
}
```

The PizzaValidator class is implemented below:

```
@Controller
public class PizzaValidator implements Validator<Pizza> {

  @Autowired
  IngredientRepository ingredientRepository;

  @Autowired
  PizzaSizeRepository pizzaSizeRepository;

  @Override
  public boolean validate(Pizza entity) {
    return validatePizza(entity);
  }

  private boolean validatePizza(Pizza pizza) {
    return validPizzaSize(pizza) && validIngredients(pizza);
  }

  private boolean validPizzaSize(Pizza pizza) {
    return pizzaSizeRepository.existsById(pizza.getSizeDesc().getId());
  }

  private boolean validIngredients(Pizza pizza) {
    for (Ingredient ingredient : pizza.getIngredients()) {
      if (!ingredientRepository.existsById(ingredient.getId())) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

For some reason it seems like Mockito isn't connecting the mock repository with my class repository, but I can't figure out why. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Never worked with Spring, but a common pitfall when working with Mockito is that you are creating objects which aren't in your CDI. My guess is that you have to inject your validator with @Autowired rather than creating a new instance yourself.

At least that's what I got from the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not create the `PizzaValidator` using `new` keyword, you should `@Autowire` it in the test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class PizzaValidatorTest {

  private Pizza meatPizza;

  @Autowire
  private PizzaValidator validator;

  @MockBean
  private IngredientRepository ingredientRepository;

  @MockBean
  private PizzaSizeRepository pizzaSizeRepository;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {

    meatPizza = new Pizza();

    }

  @Test
  public void validateValid() {
        when(ingredientRepository.existsById(any())).thenReturn(true);
        when(pizzaSizeRepository.existsById(any())).thenReturn(true);
        assertTrue(validator.validate(meatPizza));
     }
 }
```

Comment: Figured it out. It was because, in addition to what you wrote, even though it didn't matter what the ID fields of the ingredients and sizes were, since they weren't set, it was throwing an exception. Thanks!